# Why doesn't folder at solution level build?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build

The folder "Batch" and all of its contents get output to the build directory at build time. "Batch" does not appear to be part of the solution.

The folder "Config" does not get output to the build directory at build time, even though I added it to the solution (I assume it would if I added it at the project level, but I don't necessarily want it to be part of any of the projects).

[image]

A few questions:

1. Why does "Batch" get output when it's not part of the solution at all? I looked at the build template specified in the build definition and don't see it configured here either.
2. Why does "Config" not get output to the build location even though it's part of the solution? I'd like it to get output to the same location as "Batch" at build time.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you using XAML builds or vNext Builds?  Can you share the content of your csproj file as well?  It's likely something is misconfigured.

Comment: Which kind of files and contents in your config folder? What's the useage of the file `config.properties` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAML build. First make sure you are not cloaked the config folder in the build definition. Details please refer [Work with build workspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh190721%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#Build%20definition%20workspace%20example). For vNext build, it's `Repository --Mapping -- Cloak`.

If the folders are cloaked in the build definition, they will not even get sourced during the build process. Definitely in the build output.

Go through the build logs with more details such as  [diagnostic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635150.aspx#View%20diagnostic%20logs) mode in XAML, `system debug = true` in vNext to see if there are some useful info.

Moreover, also try to build the solution locally to see if got the some output.